# Программно открыть DropdownMenu (Twitter Bootstrap)

Tags: gwt, bootstrap, javascript, gwtquery

Каким образом можно программно открыть выпадающее меню компонента `DropdownButton`?

В инспекторе Хрома это можно легко осуществить, добавив элементу "btn-group" класс "open".

Пытаюсь программно добавить стиль "open" - не выставляется. Почему не добавляется этот стиль к элементу никаким образом?

Answer (score 1):

```
var Drop = $('.dropdown-toggle');
if(!Drop.hasClass('open'))
{
  Drop.dropdown('toggle');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').trigger('click');
```

Comment: Это не помогает.